# Can't remove Module from Project Structure in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to remove "library" as a module. I'm using Android Studio 3.0.1.

[image]

If I click on the red "-" it removes it but after gradle builds automatically, it adds it back again. I removed the dependency from build.gradle, so it's not used by the "app" anymore. I can't "Delete" the folder from inside Android Studio either. The only thing I can think of is to remove it from Windodows directly, but I'm really curious if it's a bug or why I can't do this from Android Studio.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show your build.gradle ?

Comment: Happened to me once, as far as I remember, I deleted **.idea** folder first, then I deleted that damn module.

Comment: Remove the module name from `settings.gradle`, and then you should be able to delete the module directory from within Android Studio. I suspect that they make this intentionally difficult, as it is not a common thing to want to do and the results can be fairly dramatic.

Comment: @CommonsWare could you please write it as the answer so I can accept it please? Thanks a bunch !

Comment: Well, IMHO, it doesn't really answer the question from your title. In terms of deleting the module from Project Structure, I have never tried that. If the Project Structure dialog offers a delete option and it doesn't work, I would consider that to be a bug. Whether the bug is that the delete option does not work, or whether the bug is that the delete option should not exist, I cannot say.

Comment: Well, it solved my problem. If anyone wants he/she can open a bug report but meh ... it's your call. It solved MY problem, so I thank you :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As @CommonsWare won't answer the question, I will do it myself.

The solution for the problem is to remove the module name from `settings.gradle` and after that, deleting the module will work normally.

Comment: Modules appears again, after IDE restart

Answer (score 4):

As @CommonsWare suggested, the solution is to open `settings.gradle` and delete the unwanted module name.

As @StayCool mentions, you can perform this solution and then restart the IDE (Android Studio) and the unwanted module(s) may reappear.

---

**I got this to work by adding the following steps.**  *It may be overkill, and some steps may do nothing, but here's what worked for me:*

---

**While IDE is open with the project:**

1. Open `settings.gradle` and delete unwanted module names, save &
   close file.
2. Delete `.gradle` folder and `.idea` folder. (do not
   delete `gradle` folder--notice the period at start of file name).
3. In IDE go to `File > Invalidate Caches/Restart` (answer affirmative to
   dialogs).

---

Your IDE should close and restart, then rebuild the folders you deleted, then the file tree should no longer show the unwanted modules.

If it doesn't work the first time, try the steps again. If it doesn't work a second time, I dunno...